# mySQL longitude and latitude query for other rows within x mile radius

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a database populated with roughly 10k rows currently. All of them have a longitude/latitude based on the center of a zipcode. I found a query that I am now attempting to expand on, but all in all it works well to a point. However, in my example below I am trying to find things within a 25 mile radius, which in all seems to work for the most part. Most of my results do yield within the 25 mile criteria, however I am getting a handful that are way off anything from 86 miles to 800 miles off the mark.

Example:
This is my center lat/lon: 37.2790669,-121.874722 = San Jose, CA
Im getting results like: 33.016928,-116.846046 = San Diego, CA which is about 355 miles from San Jose.

my current query looks like:

```
SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180))
* cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($lon - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
AS `distance` FROM `geo_locations` HAVING `distance` <= 25 ORDER BY `distance` ASC"
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Here is the query I use on the store locator I work with:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    (
        6371 *
        acos(
            cos( radians( :lat ) ) *
            cos( radians( `lat` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `long` ) - radians( :long )
            ) +
            sin(radians(:lat)) *
            sin(radians(`lat`))
        )
    ) `distance`
FROM
    `location`
HAVING
    `distance` < :distance
ORDER BY
    `distance`
LIMIT
    25
```

`:lat` and `:long` are the points the passed by the user where `lat` and `long` are the points stored in the database.

The :distance is measured in miles, in the working version of the code the :distance is actually pulled from a drop down ranging from 10-50 miles

Changing the code to work with kilometers can be accomplished by changing 3959 (the distance from the center of the earth to its surface in miles) to 6371 (3959 miles converted to kilometers) thanks to joshhendo for that solution.

Comment: Gordnfreeman, can you tell me what the "< 25" stands for? Is that 25 Miles or Kilometers? And I have another question for you if you wouldn't mind getting into a quick chat with me?

Comment: Is there any way we could easily convert this to use KM's? I presume it has something to do with the 3935 at the beginning of the query, but not quite sure what it does.

Comment: After looking into it, the 3959 is the radius of Earth in miles, so to convert to KM's I expect the only thing you'd need to do is change that to 6371 (radius of earth in KMs)

Comment: Excellent observation! I will add that up top thanks! Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.

Comment: For the sake of completeness https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

Comment: [The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)  The `LIMIT 25` has nothing to do with distance, it limits the amount of results returned.

Comment: @StijndeWitt you are correct about LIMIT in the above case but I am not sure who you were replying too. If it was my comment from 2012 I think somebody edited my original example and changed < 25 to < :distance (it would have made sense 3 years ago :D ). I am surprised this post still gets views.

Comment: @Gordnfreeman Ah that explains it... It's a good post actually and yes, geo location is getting more important by the day and your post ranks high on google

Comment: "HAVING" is the key. It allows you to use the "distance" alias in a way that "WHERE" does not.