# Using having in wp_query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can we use **having** keyword in WP_Query object of wordpress.
Say for example if I want to have it like this:-

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Latitude and Longitude are already with me so to calculate runtime distance I want to do that using pagination.
Any suggestions would be recommended.

Comment: FYI, this probably won't scale very well as it has to get all of the rows from `TableName`, calculate the `distance` value, filter *all* the results in `HAVING`, and then `ORDER` the results. You'll get much higher performance [leveraging spatial extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12540625/1427161).

Comment: I do understand that this is possible by changing mysql schema but I was looking if  I can have some condition used with wordpress wp query having condition that would be time saver for me now.

Comment: If your goal is "easy" then you can't use a `HAVING` clause with `WP_Query`. See my answer for how to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to pass an array of `post.ID` values to `WP_Query` using the [`post__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) parameter.

```
// get all the post_ids that match your spatial criteria
global $wpdb;
$sql = 'SELECT post_id FROM TableName WHERE...';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N);

// fetch the post data using the $posts_ids
$query = WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $post_ids ) );
```

I recommend coming up with a scheme using triggers and spatial indexes to perform the distance query using a bounding box and the MySQL spatial extensions. With post autosaves, history, etc this query can quickly become taxing on your server resulting in pretty terrible performance, so it doesn't scale well. Some additional details on how you might avoid this are in [this other answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540625/1427161).