# SQL How to select properties from given multiple suburbs within 5KM range with the given suburbs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, properties, postal-code

I have two table as shown below:

[tbl_properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8wG6.png) and [tbl_postcodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqCpe.png)

It shall list the properites in surrounding 5 kms of the selected postcode/s.

I am trying to get the result with below query but its not getting correct results.

```
SELECT* FROM (
```

SELECT p.*,
   ROUND(
      60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * DEGREES(
    ACOS(
      COS(RADIANS(pc.`latitude`)) * COS(RADIANS(p.`lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(pc.`longitude` - p.`lng`)) + SIN(RADIANS(pc.`latitude`)) * SIN(RADIANS(p.`lng`))
    )
      ),
      2
    ) AS distance

FROM `properties` AS p JOIN postcodes_geo AS pc ON (p.`postcode_id` = pc.`id`)

WHERE p.postcode_id IN (792,790,786,12613) 
) AS ftbl WHERE distance <= 5

Comment: Possible solution is already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8994850/4737924

Comment: Thanks for the help. This work only for one location at a time. But i want to search the records if there are multiple postcodes.

Comment: You can use UNION to collect data for multiple postcodes.

Comment: what do you mean by "not getting correct results"? are you looking for properties at most 5km away? or at a minimum of 5km?

Comment: @ awons: UNION is taking longer time. If there is another way please suggest.

Comment: @Olli: Every postcode must be compared with every properties to get the result with in 5Km (sorry i am just trying distance >=5 to check the result).

Comment: @Krishna: can you setup a sqlfiddle with some data to check some queries?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the web service which provides same feature which you require for searching based on postcode.

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Here you can pass postcode and radius as parameter and it will return list of zipcodes related to that in XML and JSON format.

for example: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?postalcode=2032&country=AU&radius=10&username=demo

Answer (score -1):

@krishna   how about   query like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT properties.*
        ,(111.045000 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(- 33.867487)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(151.206990 - lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(- 33.867487)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance
    FROM `properties`
    WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        AND lat BETWEEN - 33.912514
            AND - 33.822460
        AND lng BETWEEN 151.152763
            AND 151.261218
    ) AS properties
WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT properties.*
        ,(111.045000 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(- 33.914437)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(151.241642 - lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(- 33.914437)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance
    FROM `properties`
    WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        AND lat BETWEEN - 33.959464
            AND - 33.869411
        AND lng BETWEEN 151.187384
            AND 151.295899
    ) AS properties
WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT properties.*
        ,(111.045000 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(- 33.914437)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(151.241642 - lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(- 33.914437)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))) AS distance
    FROM `properties`
    WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        AND lat BETWEEN - 33.959464
            AND - 33.869411
        AND lng BETWEEN 151.187384
            AND 151.295899
    ) AS properties
WHERE `properties`.`deleted_at` IS NULL Limit 10
    ,10
```

This may help you  as you need  but  you need   to  little  bit work out  for   preparing  query