# Geographic coordinates in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis

There are two fields in the database table, **latitude** and **longitude**. (Other fields too, but they are not important now.)

I have a function, where are three parameters: **latitude**, **longitude** and **max_distance** (km).

Is there any way to construct raw PostgreSQL query that returns only the rows that represent location which is within that **max_distance** (km) measured from given latitude and longitude?

Example parameters latitude=59.9138699, longitude=10.7522451, max_distance=10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL longitude and latitude query for other rows within x mile radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994718/mysql-longitude-and-latitude-query-for-other-rows-within-x-mile-radius)

Comment: Maybe using the distance operator: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE  If you need this a lot you probably should look into PostGIS

Answer (score 1):

To do this, use postgis.

Postgis has functions such as [ST_Distance](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance.html) and [ST_PointFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointFromText.html):

```
select * from tbl
where ST_Distance(
    ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')', 4326), 
    ST_PointFromText('POINT(10.7522451 59.9138699)', 4326)
) < 10000;
```

To do this fast, you should use a geometry field and index it.

---

You should also learn a bit about spatial reference systems and SRID. SRID 4326 denotes the WGS84 coordinate system, commonly in use on the web.