# mysql select latitude longitude distance radius

Tags: mysql

I have two table

First one is "tbl1"

```
ID  fullName    mobile
1   Aaaa        1234567890
2   Bbbb        9874563210
3   Cccc        1237894560
```

Second is "tbl2"

```
ID  lalitude        longtitude      currentTime
2   26.90884600     75.79238500     2016-06-02 13:32:25
2   26.90884600     75.79238500     2016-06-02 13:32:25
1   26.90884600     75.79238500     2016-06-02 13:32:25
```

I have input `ID = 2` and `lalitude= 28.654490` and `longtitude = 77.267117` and `distance = 5 kilometer`.
I would like to get the list of users who are inside `5 kilometer distance` from the point `lalitude(28.654490)` and `longtitude(77.267117)` from `tbl2 with join tbl1 table`.
I am new to the geo based information.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) and convert your lat / long columns into a [POINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) and use [st_distance() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) to calculate the distance between 2 points.

Or you calculate the distances yourself using lat / long values stored as floating point numbers. For a solution see [mySQL longitude and latitude query for other rows within x mile radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994718/mysql-longitude-and-latitude-query-for-other-rows-within-x-mile-radius) topic here on SO. The accepted answer indicates how to calculate the distance in km.

Comment: what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I cannot possibly tell you what the "best" way is from your point of view. I outlined the 2 possible solutions for you. It is up to you to decide which one to go for based on your business requirement and then implement it. You may want to try both solutions and compare their speed. You also need to evaluate the overhead of using spatial data types over the regular data types.

Comment: i post my answer it worked for me, but i want to know, is that a good solution?

Comment: you are using the same formula that is in the question of the SO topic I linked.

Comment: You are not paying any attention to what I have written so far or what is in that linked topic.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_getUsersByDistance(in _ID int, in _lat decimal(10,7), in _long decimal(10,7), in _distance int)
BEGIN
    Declare _radius decimal(10,5);
    Declare _lng_min decimal(10,7);
    Declare _lng_max decimal(10,7);
    Declare _lat_min decimal(10,7);
    Declare _lat_max decimal(10,7);

    set _radius=_distance*0.621371;
    set _lng_min = _long - _radius/abs(cos(radians(_lat))*69);
    set _lng_max = _long + _radius/abs(cos(radians(_lat))*69);
    set _lat_min = _lat - (_radius/69);
    set _lat_max = _lat + (_radius/69);

    SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.latitude, tbl2.longitude,tbl2.currentTime
    from tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.ID=tbl2.ID
    where tbl2.ID=_ID and ((tbl2.latitude between _lat_min and _lat_max) and (tbl2.longitude between _lng_min AND _lng_max))
    order by tbl2.currentTime;
END
```