# show only posts which belong to a particular location of a post type, whenever I run WordPress loop with that post type

Tags: php, wordpress

The *location field* is in the meta box for each post.

Let's say post type is *listing*.

When a user entered my site I have stored his/her location in a session value.

Now I have to build a query in various short code. and don't want to repeat sane thing again and again. So is there any way to customize the wp main query for only post type listing so that when I just create a wp query object with the listing post type it will show me only those posts which belong to the current location.

Comment: See for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994718/mysql-longitude-and-latitude-query-for-other-rows-within-x-mile-radius